# Trigonometry question finding the sin and tan

Tags: trigonometry

If angle $\alpha$ is reflex, and $\cos \alpha = -\frac{9}{41}$, without using a calculator, evaluate

(a) $\sin \alpha$
(b) $\tan \alpha$
(c) $\cos (\alpha - 180\deg)$     .

Answer (score 2):

(a) You know $\cos(\alpha)$, so you can use $\sqrt{\sin^2(\alpha)+\cos^2(\alpha)}=1$ to solve for $\sin^2(\alpha)$. $\alpha$ is reflex, so $\sin(\alpha) < 0$, so you'll want to go with the negative solution.

(b) You know $\sin(\alpha)$ and $\cos(\alpha)$. Just plug into the formula for $\tan(\alpha)$ and evaluate.

(c) I'm assuming it means $1800^{\circ}$? $1800(\text{mod}360) = 0$, so the angle is essentially the same (you're just making full trips around the circle). So, $\cos(\alpha) = \cos(\alpha-1800)$. And you already know $\cos(\alpha)$.

Comment: Hi Aricha, thank you very much your for your comment. However, I'm not totally sure what to do as a first step? Divide -9 by 41 and then inverse it? If I do that I don't end up with a reflex angle, it's 103 degrees when rounded. I also don't fully understand the square root identity.

Comment: @user136213 That identity comes from the unit circle (it's the Pythagorean identity): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Pythagorean_identity As for solving, You know the value of $\cos(\alpha)$. So just plug it into the Pythagorean identity and solve for $\sin^2(\alpha)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for that table of identities, very helpful! On the question, I don't know the value of cos(a), I'm not sure what to do with it? Do I inverse cos -9/41 but then I'm left with 103 degrees when rounded and that angle isn't reflex.

Comment: You don't need to do any inverses when solving for $\sin^2(\alpha)$. You already know $\cos(\alpha)$, so literally just plug it in. That is, solve $\sqrt{\sin^2(\alpha)+(\tfrac{-9}{41})^2}=1$.

Comment: @user136213 This will of course return two solutions: $-\sqrt{\sin^2(\alpha)}$ and $\sqrt{\sin^2(\alpha)}$. Which is the appropriate choice given that the angle is reflex?

Comment: Two solutions for $\sin(\alpha)$, that is.

Comment: Aaaah, I understand that bit, thank you, I won't make that mistake again (about the cos of the angle). However, I don't know what sin is. That identity doesn't make total sense to me unfortunately. I know that sin being positive or negative is down to where it is on the CAST system, but I don't know what sin2(a) is; I don't know the hypotenuse. And how would that equal 1?

Comment: I think it would be positive in this case

Comment: @user136213 Well, you want a reflex angle. So, $\sin(\alpha) < 0$. Also, here's an image that shows where the identity comes from: http://www.mathwarehouse.com/trigonometry/pythagorean-identity/images/picture-graph-of-pythagorean-identity-formula.gif And then we can just take the square root of both sides.

Comment: How do I find the hypotenuse? I'm not sure how I'd find sin(a) without the hypotenuse?

Comment: Look at it this way: consider a circle of radius $r$ instead of the unit circle. Also consider the polar equivalents of $x$ and $y$ ($r\cos(\theta)$ and $r\sin(\theta)$), respectively. So, $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ becomes $r^2\sin^2(\theta)+r^2\cos^2(\theta)=r^2$. Now divide everything by $r^2$. :)

Comment: @user136213 And there's your identity. The radius doesn't actually matter.

Comment: Couldn't I find the hypotenuse by doing x2 = -9x2 + 41x2 then adding them up and finding the square root (this thing won't let me press enter). I'm not really understanding your explanation sorry.

Comment: @user136213 You could, but there's no point. You don't actually need to know the hypotenuse to solve for the angle. Why? Because the size of the triangle could be scaled up or down, but the measure of the angle would stay the same.

Comment: Would you mind writing out how you'd find sin(a) so I could make sense of your explanation? I'm really finding it hard to grasp this, sorry.

Comment: @user136213 Sure. First, substitute $\cos{\alpha}$ into the expression. So, we have $\sqrt{\sin^2(\alpha)+(\frac{-9}{41})^2}=1$. Square both sides to get $\sin^2(\alpha)+(\frac{-9}{41})^2=1$. See where to go from here?

Comment: Thank you :), I guess you'd switch the 1 over and minus the -9/412 from it to get sin2(a) and then inverse? But I don't see how you just squared both sides, all I can see is that you removed the square root sign but nothing changed.

Comment: @user136213 Squaring the left side just removes the square root symbol. On the right side, $1^2=1$, so nothing changes.